# Duplicate column values by value in second column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
a<-c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')

b<-c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3)

df<-data.frame(a, b)

      a b
    1 a 1
    2 b 2
    3 c 3
    4 d 2
    5 e 3
```

I would like to duplicate the values in column a by the number in column b, so as to get a vector/data.frame that looks like this:

```
c<-c('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e')

       c
    1  a
    2  b
    3  b
    4  c
    5  c
    6  c
    7  d
    8  d
    9  e
    10 e
    11 e
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: how about `rep(a, b)` ? The key word might be 'replicate' instead of 'duplicate'

Comment: @liuminzhao That sounds like an answer, not a comment! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `?rep`, as in:

```
> with(df, rep(a, times = b))
 [1] a b b c c c d d e e e
Levels: a b c d e
```

The factor bit is annoying as it is how R created `b` in `df`. Either do

```
> df <- data.frame(a, b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> with(df, rep(a, times = b))
 [1] "a" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "d" "d" "e" "e" "e"
```

then the above answer, or just coerce the result to a character vector:

```
> with(df, as.character(rep(a, times = b)))
 [1] "a" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "d" "d" "e" "e" "e"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to expand you entire `data.frame`, you can use something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                 b = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3))
df[rep(rownames(df), df$b), ]
#     a b
# 1   a 1
# 2   b 2
# 2.1 b 2
# 3   c 3
# 3.1 c 3
# 3.2 c 3
# 4   d 2
# 4.1 d 2
# 5   e 3
# 5.1 e 3
# 5.2 e 3
```